# Kotlin интеграционные тесты для spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot, функциональное-тестирование

Что у меня есть: есть микросервис на Spring boot, с вебом и MongoDB как сторадж. Для интеграционных тестов я использую test container. Для тестирования микросервиса написаны 2 интаграционных теста с SpringBootTest аннатацией и для них есть TestConfig класс для поднятия контейнера mongodb.

В чем проблема: если запускать тесты по одиночке они проходят, но если запускать одновременно, они падают. 
**MongoContainerConfig.kt**

```
@TestConfiguration
class MongoContainerConfig {

    var mongoContainer: GenericContainer<Nothing>

    constructor() {
        mongoContainer = FixedHostPortGenericContainer<Nothing>("mongo")
                .withFixedExposedPort(27018,27017)
        mongoContainer.start()
    }

    @PreDestroy
    fun close() {
        mongoContainer.stop()
    }
}
```

**First test**

```
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = arrayOf(MongoContainerConfig::class, AssertUtilsConfig::class),
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
class CardControllerTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {}
}
```

**Second test**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = arrayOf(MongoContainerConfig::class, AssertUtilsConfig::class))
class PositiveTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {}
}
```

**Error msg**

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoContainerConfig': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.lang.card.engcard.config.MongoContainerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e58ffeee]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    a
```

Данный проект есть на github и данную ошибку можно посмотреть на CI https://github.com/GSkoba/eng-card/runs/576320155?check_suite_focus=true

Самое смешное, что если переписать тесты и конфиг на java, то все работает)

Comment: Ошибка свидетельствует о том, что не может создаться bean для подключения к mongo. То есть параметры для mongo неверные.

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий если обратиться к документации [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing-ctx-management) по интаг тестированию, то есть механизм кэширования контекста, т.е. в данном случае spring должен один раз поднять контейнер, шардировать его на все тесты и завершить его работу после завершения тестов

Comment: Если параметры для бина отвечающего за подключение к базе неверный, то spring не успевает поднять контекст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хаха, это было не легко) 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching
Тесты имеют разный контекст и поэтому MongoContainerConfig вызывается 2 раза.
Фикс - добавить webEnv в CardControllerTest.kt

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = arrayOf(MongoContainerConfig::class, AssertUtilsConfig::class),
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class PositiveTest
```

Proof https://github.com/GSkoba/eng-card/actions/runs/78094215